# Methods to measure output variable in a feedback system

Tags: control-system, sampling, controller, negative-feedback

\$R(t)\$ is reference signal, \$U\$ is controlled input, \$Y\$ is output of the plant, **Ts=1 s** is sampling time (i.e. after each 1 sec output and reference is compared) and input output relation of the plant is

$$\dot y=a y+cU$$

[image: block diagram for a feedback loop]

what value of \$y(t)\$ we consider when we compare \$y(t)\$ and \$r(t)\$ during each sampling interval ?

I think there may be two different values (methods) of  \$y(t)\$ is possible at after every sampling interval

1. Actual (physical) plant output which can be measured by sensors after each  sampling interval and then compare with reference Signal and then modify controlled input
2. Calculated (using approximation) plant output using relation

$$y_1=y_0+\dot y_0 T_s$$
$$\dot y_0=a y_0+cU_0$$

And in this case we need sensor only at \$t=0\$ after that we can calculate mathematically  $$ y_1,y_2 ,y_3 \dots$$
And then these values can be compared with reference signal.

So, which procedure is generally followed or preferred? Are both methods valid or not?

Comment: Hi @Chu  , I'm not sure whether the second method i mentioned makes any sense specially after reading other answers but still I cannot find what's wrong with second approach

Comment: Your question is not clear. Measure or calculate? If you're trying to derive a relationship between R and Y, the z-transform is the appropriate method for a hybrid system.

Comment: @Chu , in 2nd method I thought When we measure Y at t=0 using sensor and at that moment by comparing with reference Signal controller produces U(0) at t=0 and we know derivative of Y can be changed instantly due to this relation
y˙0=ay0+cU0
but Y will not instantly because it is like an integration so by approximating integration we can say at t=1 when we again compare with reference ,it's value approximate would be
y1=y0+y˙0Ts
and this process continues.. it would be helpful if you can tell where or which assumption of mine is not correct in above statement .

Comment: This looks like homework. How, exactly, is the question phrased?

Comment: @Chu , it is for the algorithm of mpc controller for changing the lane of car in an online course and not a homework problem

Comment: OK, so what is the question?

Comment: @Chu , does second method works ? Or is it even makes any sense ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the intent of your question correctly, the short answer is that you would generally use the actual measurement from the sensor and then design your controller so that it performs well even though the measurement has a delay. Using predicted plant outputs is a more advanced controller which may or may not be required.

You have mixed up a bunch of things in this question. Mainly continuous and discrete time systems in both your notations and your assumptions. Your illustration and plant model is in continuous time, but later on you use a discrete model for calculating \$y_1\$.

When you want to calculate the output of the plant, that calculation is basically a model of your plant. For that calculation to be performed every \$ Ts \$ seconds and still be accurate, you will have to convert the continuous time equations (model) to discrete (model) using some approximation. Using the notation \$ \dot{y} \$ in a discrete model makes no sense. There are multiple ways of doing this. Zero-order hold is what you are indirectly using from your equation.

After you do this, you will get a discrete model that looks like this:
$$
y_{k+1} = Ay_k + BU_k
$$
Depending on the method you choose, it is not necessary that \$ BU_k = \dot{y_0}T_s \$

Now you can use this equation for future state prediction. If you decide to keep the sensor after doing this you can combine the prediction with your sensor reading to get a more accurate measurement (this starts going into observers and Kalman filters).

However, if you decide to get rid of the sensor, there are problems you have not considered. If there is any disturbance, noise or you are even slightly wrong about the parameters, over time your prediction will deviate from the actual output of your plant. You basically have a complicated feed forward controller that might not even do a good job of controlling the output.

Comment: Hi , I used continuous equation because our plant is an continuous system and controller is discrete system and i was trying to understand how minimization of cost function using future predicted state of plant and U of controller track the reference without help of sensor , but in all answers it was suggested that i cannot use continuous equation for discrete system but when plant is continuous System (although controller is not) so why I cannot use these equations for our plant and it's future state prediction ? Thanks for your answer

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify these things.

Answer (score 1):

Add any noise to each of your \$\dot{y}_n\$ (or even to a single one) and try to "calculate mathematically \$y_1,y_2 ,y_3 \dots\$" and it won't work. Now if you have measurements \$y_{n-1}\$ at time \$n\$ you might have a shot of actually getting the system to behave.
Basically, your second approach of measuring the initial state and no longer using feedback will not work. Might look good on paper but any added noise will ruin the idea.

Also, you are abusing notation by talking about discrete systems using derivatives and assuming that \$\int_{0+t}^{T_s+t} \dot{y}(\tau)d\tau = T_s \dot{y}(t)\$

Comment: Hi , I used continuous equation because our plant is an continuous system and controller is discrete system and i was trying to understand how minimization of cost function using future predicted state of plant and U of controller track the reference without help of sensor , but in all answers it was suggested that i cannot use continuous equation for discrete system but when plant is continuous System (although controller is not) so why I cannot use these equations for our plant and it's future state prediction ? Thanks for your answer

Comment: If your question was on how MPC works you should have asked that, it would have been easier for people to answer that directly. MPC does use feedback (continuously sampling the system), but it also uses a simplified/wrong prediction to be able to determine each of the control values \$u_k\$. Basically, every period the MPC controller will get a measurement from the sensor \$y_{n-1}\$, set up an optimization and solve it to find the next \$u_k\$.

Comment: The problem is not discretizing the system (even though I criticized your notation.) The thing is, if you only measure the system once and keep using "prediction" to control it you are basically doing open-loop control. And any error/noise you have will never be corrected, it will pile up and lead to huge problems.

Answer (score 1):

One must do some reasoning to understand how your system works.

You wrote:

> Ts=1 s is sampling time (i.e. after each 1 sec output and reference is
> compared)

That cannot happen in the plant because its law contains a derivative which is nonsense in discrete time systems.

So, it must be the controller who decides new U at every second and keeps it available in the plant input until new value is outputted. Otherwise this all is pure nonsense starting from your drawing.

The plant generates continuously Y as the operating law differential equation states. The controller gets that Y and R(t) and produces new U after every 1 second. The plant uses Y and U continuously to evolve Y. The controller samples its input every second.

If you want to calculate how Y evolves as the time goes on you must know input signal R(t), the initial state of Y, parameters a and c and how U is formed from R(t)-Y(t). None of the rest of us can give it without guessing.

If you plan computer simulation you must use simulation time step which is short enough to present properly Y(t) and what happens in the controller. Generally selecting good simulation step needs some tests and without rigorous math analysis it's more or less gambling.

Comment: I thought When we measure Y at t=0 using sensor and at that moment by comparing with reference Signal controller produces U(0) at t=0 and we know derivative of Y can be changed instantly due to this relation  $$\dot y_0=a y_0+cU_0$$ but Y  will not instantly because it is like an integration so by approximating integration we can say at t=1 when we again compare with reference ,it's value approximate would be $$ y_1=y_0+\dot y_0 T_s$$ and this process continues.. it would be helpful if you can tell where or which assumption of mine is not correct in above statement .

Comment: You are doing what I said: Making a discrete time simulation by using time step =1s and the simplest (=Euler's) form of numerical integration. That can work if a and cU are so small that the caused divergence from exactly calculated result is so small that the cumulated error during the full simulation period is small enough. As I said one should test which is small enough simulation step. 1s can well be good if the time constants in the system are for ex. 1 hour and you run the simulation only a day. If Y changes remarkably (assuming it obeys the given continuous time law) during 1s you fail.

Comment: Thanks +1 , so does it mean that after t=0 ,we don't need sensor to measure Y of plant instead we can use this calculated (approximated) Y  and compare with reference and run the loop ?

Comment: If you have a real plant you cannot exactly calculate what it does. Controllers are needed because operating laws are approximate. In real systems there's always something unknown - think it as noise summed to the plant output or to a point inside the plant. The effect of that noise should be compensated by the controller. If you imagine certain operating law to be exactly true - that's possible if everything happens only in math you need no such thing as sensor. Calculated Y is available as is and your asked method works (assuming your time step is short enough).